# Aristotle's "Man is a political/social animal" original Greek words

Tags: ancient-greek, greek-to-english-translation

The following sentence by Artistotle is well-known:

> Man is a political/social animal.

His original words are:

> διότι δὲ πολιτικὸν ὁ ἄνθρωπος ζῷον πάσης μελίττης καὶ παντὸς ἀγελαίου ζῴου μᾶλλον, δῆλον. οὐθὲν γάρ, ὡς φαμέν, μάτην ἡ φύσις ποιεῖ ([source](https://wist.info/aristotle/45687/))

This is in ancient Greek. Which words refer to "a political/social animal"? Which word has been translated as either political or social? Which do you think is the better English equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> πολιτικὸν ὁ ἄνθρωπος ζῷον

The above is the basic statement. ὁ ἄνθρωπος is "man" (as in person, human being, not particular a male), and πολιτικὸν ζῷον is "political animal."

It should be noted that πολιτικὸν is the adjective derived from the Greek πόλις, which means "city." While it can mean "political" (as in related to politician), Aristotle here is likely referring more to the idea that people naturally congregate and create shared living spaces (i.e. cities). That's why he compares us to bees (μελίττης) or herd animals (ἀγελαίου).

Of course, a Greek would understand some of the various nuances that accompany such a use.

Which word is better is a matter of opinion. Using "political" keeps to the etymology of πολιτικος, but using "social" is perhaps more accurate here.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's an even more explicit statement of this earlier in the *Politics* in 1153a1-3: "ἐκ τούτων οὖν φανερὸν . . . ὅτι ὁ ἄνθρωπος φύσει πολιτικὸν ζῷον. . . ."

Comment: @brianpck May you type the English translation?

Comment: "From these things it is clear . . . that man is by nature a political/social animal."

Comment: Why would ἄνθρωπος be _man_ instead of _human_? As you point out, it is not about being male, so I was surprised that you chose a gendered term, thereby necessitating your disclaimer. Wouldn't it be simpler to say it's _human_?

Comment: @terdon: *Man* is normally used in the genderless sense in such contexts, not referring to a masculine human. As in *mankind*, etc. *Human* is i.m.o. not a felicitous translation, but it would be technically correct, certainly.

Comment: The linguistic shift to use of nongendered terms is quite recent. Before that shift, the disclaimer was commonly understood, but after that shift has become more necessary. @terdon

Comment: Yes, I know the ungendered meaning of _man_, but it just seemed like a poor choice here as it introduces ambiguity not present in the original Greek (to my, admittedly limited, knowledge) or with the term _human_. Why do you say it would not be a felicitous translation? I may be getting swayed by my knowledge of Modern Greek where άνθρωπος is the 100% direct translation of _human_ for me (I'm a native speaker of Greek and English).

Comment: On the other hand I believe use of the English phrase "man is a political animal" as the translation of that Greek phrase goes quite far back; it might be interesting to know how far.

Comment: Oh indeed, and I'm not advocating changing the actual expression! I was just wondering why cmw, who I am sure knows a _lot_ more than I do about both Ancient Greek and most likely English, chose to write "ὁ ἄνθρωπος is "man" (as in person, human being, not particular a male)" instead of just saying "ὁ ἄνθρωπος is 'human'". I now see it was probably simply to keep consistency with the idiomatic expression, but I was wondering if there may have been a deeper etymological reason.

Comment: @Cerberus sorry, I didn't realize you had commented, so I didn't ping you. Please see my comment above asking about why it would not be a felicitous translation and delete this one. Your knowledge of both English and Ancient Greek far outstrips mine so I'm sure you have a point.

Comment: @terdon To my ear, *man* without an article and in the singular always refers to humans as a whole and not specifically to males. If I said "men are political animals" or "the man is a political animal", I'd hear that, in Modern, as specifically referring to males. But in the singular and without an article it's gender neutral to me.

Comment: I'm also a fan of etymology, and etymologically speaking, *man* used to be that gender-neutral term for both *weras* and *wīf* in Old English. An alternative approach to shunning it and using a Latin borrowing is to reclaim it in its original sense and argue for it. That aside, it's also fairly standard in other sentences, too, such as "man is the measure of all things" (πάντων χρημάτων **ἄνθρωπον** μέτρον εἶναι).

Comment: That said, I'm not insensitive to gendered language, so thanks for bringing it up. I also wonder if my ears might not lean archaic, and perhaps a younger crowd wouldn't hear it the same way, but that's why I put that disclaimer in afterwards. Just in case.

Comment: Guys, Aristotle would have indeed lost his mind and go full crazy before writing something like “man and woman are by nature political animals.” Or probably ended up as Socrates did, had he proposed universal suffrage in Athens. As  L. P. Hartley opened his _The Go-Between:_ “The past is a foreign country; they do things differently there.” He was talking about the 50-some year past of the good old Britain. Athens _was_ a foreign country, and Aristotle wrote 2500 year ago, give or take. Politically correcting his thought _du jour_ would make it a deleteriously disastrous disservice.

Comment: @cmw I am not arguing that _man is a social animal_ should be changed (eek!) nor even that it is ambiguous. I'm not even arguing at all, just hoping to learn something. My question is why you chose the word _man_ instead of _human_ for your own translation of the standalone Ancient Greek word _ἄνθρωπος_. If it was just a question of personal stylistic choice, I have no issue whatsoever. I was just curious whether there was a deeper etymological reason, that's all. Since in modern Greek, one would never use man (άνδρας) in a gender neutral way, translating it as _man_ struck me as odd.

Comment: @kkm I will definitely never deny Aristotle's misogyny (it's as clear as day!), but on the other hand, he did use ἄνθρωπος and not ἀνήρ. And moreover, the masculine aspect isn't being emphasized here. Men and women live in πολεῖς, not only men. It's not politics he's talking about, but our gregarious nature. But certainly your point about Aristotle's distance from us is not inaccurate in general.

Comment: @terdon All good! Not arguing either, just trying to flesh out some reasons for the choice. By the way, I believe άνδρας actually comes from ἀνήρ, not ἄνθρωπος. I think there's a good question to be asked on the topic, though. It would certainly get more exposure from others who could chime in.

Comment: (Or feel free to stop by the chat if these comments become too unwieldy.)

Comment: It seems to me that the very concept of gendered language as we see it haven't existed at his time. Even less did the _inverted_ Sapir-Worfian belief that language must be changed to reflect modern equality of the sexes. It's notable that while some English speakers are trying to invent non-gendered pronouns, the speakers of e.g. Slavic languages, where nouns are gendered, who are acting in the same vein, are insisting on creating gendered counterparts to non-matching e.g. profession names, like “She is a doctoress,” since “doctor” is masc. Both efforts are linguistically futile, indeed.